# Access Denied while accessing file in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Access denied while trying to access an object in S3 bucket

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>E1A762D4995831AD</RequestId>
  <HostId>
avopDC2byf3O3Lo1BkugPXL3X76tqzaWgdxAHS3rnDZx3OHgjot69A7NGw9f6E7icTcv0jgubGM=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

I have the following policies that might be relevant are attached to IAM user

1. AWSS3FullAccess
2. AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser

Server side encryption is enabled on the bucket *Server side encryption: AWS-KMS*

I'm not in the list of aws accounts with access to the bucket, when we tried to add using my canonical userid which is also my email address, we get `The e-mail address you provided does not match any account on record.`

The same setting prevails in some other buckets as well, except they are not **Server side encrypted**, which I can access with no problem.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question to add more details? For example, what do you mean by "trying to access"? Can anybody else access the S3 objects? How were the objects put into the bucket (it is possible that they could be copied from another account without an appropriate `acl` so they are inaccessible)? How are you accessing the objects -- via a URL, or via the S3 console? Anything more you give us would be helpful!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Done, let me know if you need more information

Comment: So, you're saying that the Bucket is in Account A, and you are in Account B? What is the Bucket Policy? If you can access the exact same scenario for other buckets that don't use KMS encryption, then the problem is that the account with the bucket ("Account A") is not granting you KMS permissions, so you cannot decrypt the file. It doesn't matter what permissions you give yourself in your own account, the account that owns the bucket has to be the one granting you the permissions.

Comment: No, both are under same account id, just different IAM users. One of them is the owner of the bucket

Comment: Problem was with the permission to the key `aws kms create-grant --key-id "arn:aws:kms:<region>:<accountid>:<keyid>" --grantee-principal "arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:user/<userid>" --operations "Encrypt" "Decrypt"` solved it, Thanks @JohnRotenstein

Comment: *"One of them is the owner of the bucket"*  Note for reference that buckets are owned by the entire AWS account, not by a specific IAM user.

Comment: Are you trying to access in a browser? What permission do you have defined for your AWS S3 Bucket? Any policy (AWS S3 Bucket policy) in play - If Yes, do anonymise and share as relevant?